# List of integers without any arithmetic progression of n terms

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let's consider a positive integer $n$ and the list of the $n^2$ integers from $1$ to $n^2$. What is the minimum number $f(n)$ of integers to be cancelled in this list so that it is impossible to form  any arithmetic progression of $n$ terms with the remaining integers?

Comment: Could you comment on the source of this question?

Comment: $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=4$, $f(3)=4$. Do you have some more numbers to report?

Comment: Isn't $f(2)=3$?

Comment: Uh, yep, $f(2)=3$. I did $f(3)$ on my fingers, too, so no promises...

Comment: If $n+1$ is prime, we have a linear upper bound $f(n)\le2n$: Removing $\{n\}\cup\{k(n+1)|k=1,...,n-1\}\cup\{k(n+1)+1|k=1,...,n-2\}$ should do the job. (Display the numbers 1,...,n² in order in a rectangle with $n+1$ columns to see why.)

Comment: For those who want to code this in a less brute force way, this is an example of a set cover problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem: Let $X$ be the set of all $n$ term arithmetic progressions contained in $[n]$ and let $Y_i \subset X$ be the set of progressions containing $i$. Then we want to find a minimal way of writing $X = Y_{i_1} \cup Y_{i_2} \cup \cdots \cup Y_{i_r}$. If I understand the Wikipedia article correctly, the problem is NP-hard, but nonetheless there are smarter things to do than pure brute force.

Answer (score 12):

**EDIT:** The original values of $f$ that I reported were the result of a buggy program, as noted by Wolfgang in the comments.  I have fixed the bug and corrected the results.

---

This problem is easily coded up as an integer linear program.  For $1\le i\le n^2$, let $x_i$ be a 0-1 variable indicating whether $i$ is chosen.  Minimize $\sum_i x_i$ subject to the constraints $\sum_{a\in A} x_a \ge 1$ for every arithmetic progression $A$ of interest.

Assuming no bugs in my program, it took CPLEX only a few minutes to extend JiK's list of small values to:

$$
\begin{align}
f(8)&=13 &&\{6,13,18,23,28,36,37,38,39,40,43,50,57\} \\
f(9)&=15 &&\{8,15,22,29,32,41,42,43,44,45,46,54,61,68,75\} \\
f(10)&=16 &&\{10,15,22,29,36,43,53,55,56,57,58,68,73,74,84,91\}\\
f(11)&=18 && \{11,22,33,44,55,60,66,68,72,76,77,85,92,97,99,102,106,111\}
\end{align}
$$

The last of these took less than 15 minutes on a six-core machine (about 400,000 "ticks" in CPLEX parlance).
I'm sure that cleverer techniques could push the computation further, but this is already enough to show that the OEIS doesn't already know about this sequence.

Comment: sorry to deceive you, but at least for f(8) you missed the "8x8" diagonal sequence 1,10,19,...,64. Similar for n=10 with 1,12,...,100. Both times the only possible one of distance >n. That may be the reason your algorithm stopped so quickly. :( :(

Comment: Wolfgang, you are correct.  I found the bug in my program, reran CPLEX, and edited my answer accordingly.  The corrected runs took about the same amount of time to run.

Comment: The corrected sequence matches (except for the beginning) https://oeis.org/A077117 , but this may be a coincidence.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek that is a coincidence because A077117 grows too quickly, e.g. $a(20)=38>37\ge f(20)$.

Answer (score 11):

This is not a complete answer, but a reasonable estimate.

Fix a prime $(1-o(1))n<p<n$. Every length-$n$ arithmetic progression with the difference co-prime with $p$ contains an element divisible by $p$; hence, removing all multiples of $p$ from $[1,n^2]$, we kill all such progressions. Now, every progression with the difference $d<n$ *not* co-prime with $p$ actually has $d=p$ (recall that $2p>n$). The set of all integers from $[1,n^2]$, not divisible by $p$, splits into $p-1$ progressions with difference $p$, each of these progressions having length $n^2/p+O(1)<2n$; removing just one element in the middle of every such progression kills all length-$n$ progressions with difference $p$. Altogether, we have removed $(n^2/p)+p+O(1)<2(1+o(1))n$ elements from $[1,n^2]$. As a result,
  $$ n\le f(n) < (2+o(1))n, $$
the lower bound following from the trivial observation that one must remove at least one element from every subinterval $[kn+1,(k+1)n],\ 0\le k<n$.

Comment: Having my answer submitted, I noticed a comment by Wolfgang which appeared while I was typing. My answer is based on the very same idea, of course.

Comment: So this construction reduces to the number theoretic question: if n+1 is not prime, how small can we get the o(1) term. But looking at the initial values, there might be some space to improve the upper bound to around $\frac32 n$.

Comment: According to the first estimates for n=1,2,...,8 (see above), I conjecture f(n)=  2n- 2 for n >2. What do you think about it?

Comment: @BernardVignes Note that f(6)=9 as mentioned in a comment by JiK. Remove 6,10,11,12,19,21,26,28,31.

Comment: It would be interesting to get a better lower bound than $n$. I don't see any easy way to do so.

Comment: @Timothy: my wild guess is that considering progressions with just two carefully chosen differences ($n$ and $n-1$?) may suffice. I think the first step would be to verify this numerically.

Comment: A few minutes' thought shows how one can get a lower bound of $n+1$. Arranging the elements in a square and considering rows and columns shows that if we want to get away with only $n$, then we have to pick a transversal. Then it is not hard to see that to also hit every sequence of $n$ consecutive integers, the only transversal that could work is the anti-diagonal. It is then trivial that the anti-diagonal does not work. This is a pretty ad hoc argument and $n+1$ is hardly impressive, but at least it shows that there is no serious barrier to doing better than $n$.

Answer (score 8):

Extending my comment to an answer for small $n$: a brute force program gives

$$
\begin{align}
f(1)&=1 &&\{1\}  \\ 
f(2)&=3 &&\{1,2,3\} \\
f(3)&=4 &&\{3,4,5,7\} \\
f(4)&=6 &&\{3,4,5,6,10,13\} \\
f(5)&=7 &&\{3, 7, 9, 10, 11, 16, 21\} \\
f(6)&=9 &&\{5, 8, 12, 14, 15, 16, 21, 26, 31\} \\
f(7)&=11 &&\{3, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 22, 29, 36, 43\} \\
f(8)&=13 &&\{7, 10, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 29, 36, 43, 50, 57\}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Writing the arrays in reverse order in an $n\times n$ square, your pattern for 
$n=5$ is $\pmatrix{.  &  .  & . & . & o \\ 
. & . & . & . & o \\
. & . & . & . & o \\ 
o & o & . & o & . \\ 
. & . & o & . & .}$ and for $n=7$  
$\pmatrix{. & . & . & . & . & . & o\\
. & . & . & . & . & . & o\\
. & . & . & . & . & . & o\\
. & . & . & . & . & . & o\\
. & . & . & . & . & . & o\\
o & o & o & o & . & o & .\\
. & . & . & . & o & . & .}
 $. They immediately generalize yielding $f(p)\le 2p-3$ for primes $p\ge5$.

Comment: Likewise, the pattern for 
$n=6$ written in 5 columns is $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ $\pmatrix{
.&.&.&.&.\\
o&.&.&.&.\\
o&.&.&.&.\\
o&.&.&.&.\\
o&o&o&.&o\\
.&.&.&o&.\\
.&o&.&.&.\\.&&&&}$ This extends to $\pmatrix{
.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
o&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
o&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
o&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
o&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
o&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
o&o&o&o&o&.&o\\
.&.&.&.&.&o&.\\
.&o&.&.&.&.&.\\.&&&&&&}$ for $n=8$ and generalizes yielding $f(n)\le 2n-3$ for $n=p+1, p\ge5$.

Comment: Can you check with your program if $8,15,22,29, 36,38,46,47,49,51,55,58$ qualifies for $f(8)\le12$?

Comment: @Wolfgang $1,7,13,19,25,31,37,43$ is a counterexample.

Comment: oops, thank you. I've missed that 1 goes with that diagonal. This makes me think that $f(8)\le13$ is sharp. :( I suppose brute force takes too much time for $n=8$?

Comment: I currently have $11\leq f(8) \leq 13$. The check for cases $11$ and $12$ should take around 4 and 18 hours (I'll hopefully report the results tomorrow), but $n=9$ seems to be too much.

Comment: I'd have a hard time believing $f(8)=11$ anyway. And 12 seems so tight, if at all, there should be very very few solutions.

Answer (score 0):

For the first values of n my best estimates of f(n) are the following:

f(1) = 1,

f(2) = 3 and for example the remaining integer is 1,

f(3) = 4 and for example the remaining integers are 1,2,6,8,9

f(4) = 6 and for example the remaining integers are 1,2,3,5,8,9,12,14,15,16

f(5) = 8 and for example the remaining integers are 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,12,14,15,18,19,20,22,23, 24,25

f(6) = 10

f(7) = 12

....

I wonder if the conjecture f(n) = 2n - 2 for n>2 is appropriate and can be demonstrated or not.